# Installing AWS SDK for .NET seems to have broken Unity VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, unityvs

After installing AWS SDK for .NET, I can no longer open my Unity project in Visual Studio. I've tried doing it through the Unity menu (Visual Studio Tools -> Open in Visual Studio), I've tried opening the solution from Visual Studio (I get errors that the imported projects cannot be found), I've tried closing/opening Unity and Visual Studio, rebooting, uninstalling/reinstalling UnityVS, uninstalling the AWS toolkit... and I'm out of ideas. Is there any precedent for an issue like this? I guess the next step would be to reinstall Unity and/or Visual Studio...

Comment: There is no error when trying to open from the unity menu, it just doesn't work. The error in Visual Studio about the imported projects is "[project path] : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\SyntaxTree\UnityVS\2013\UnityVS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [project path]"

Comment: Update: Reinstalling Unity didn't work, but I followed the path mentioned in the above error. 2013\UnityVS.CSharp.targets didn't exist, but 2012\UnityVS.CSharp.targets did. If I create the 2013 folder and copy/paste the .targets file over, I can open the project in Visual Studio, though it gives me the warning "Visual Studio Tools: Visual Studio 2013 not found."

This is a decent workaround, but I still can't open the project through the Unity menu, and it really shouldn't be pointing to that 2013 folder. Does anyone know how to set the target path correctly?

Comment: Just re-install everything :)

Comment: Just installed for VS2012 and running into the same problem. No error only a warning `Visual Studio Tools: Visual Studio 2012 not found`. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Try using AWS SDK for Unity